# Trying to import a .wav file to use in my Pythonista (3) script from my computer

Tags: python, pythonista

I am making a little game on Pythonista 3, and I want to transfer an audio(.wav) file from my computer to use in this game, but cannot figure out how. I have an IPhone 4 on ios 9.3.5.

I have tried through a simple USB connection, but apple dosen't allow .wav files to be put in any of the directories available.

Comment: Have you tried using iCloud? You run an FTP server in Pythonista (search for PythoistaFTP on github, or install StaSh) you can connect to it from your PC/Mac and upload whatever you like.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply @SimonHibbs ! I looked into this for a little while and found this GitHub: [link](https://gist.github.com/omz/1aec8a66a5d5d19a36ab) I found that when running this (in python 2.7 and 3.6) I got a bunch of errors. After some more searching, I could not find the answer to my problem. If you could explain a bit more about what you did, that would help a bunch. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like it's out of date. Maybe try Stash, it has loads of useful utilities but I've not used it for a while. https://github.com/ywangd/stash/